# Gmail property missing from event fired from gmail add-on contextualTriggers

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm redeveloping an gmail addon I wrote in the past (yay typescript and clasp) and I'm trying to support mobile.  I'm searching the message content using the following to get the message

```
function onGmailMessage(e) {
  console.log(e);
  // Get the ID of the message the user has open.
  let messageId = e.gmail.messageId;

  // Get an access token scoped to the current message and use it for GmailApp
  let accessToken = e.gmail.accessToken;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
```

This works great on when called from a desktop browser.  However, when called from mobile iOS Gmail the gmail property is missing from e. I'm using V8 runtime with the following scopes:

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.addons.metadata.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
```

Should this be available, or is there a different approach to support mobile/iOS?

Thanks
-Matt

Comment: When you say `However, when called from mobile iOS Gmail the gmail property is missing from e` do you mean the Gmail Apps Store App, or Gmail in your mobile browser?

Comment: I was using the Gmail iOS app and not the web interface.  I found that the depreciated messageMetadata property is still vis available in all contexts.